# Unable to load 'paypal' section from your config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal

I'm experiencing a problem with PayPal SDK for .NET. I've filled out my settings in the Web.config, but when I try to use the PayPal SDK's ConfigManager to fetch these settings, it comes up with the following error:

```
Unable to load 'paypal' section from *.config: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for paypal: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

I was hoping someone might have experienced this issue before, or otherwise knows how to help me.

I've also tried loading the Web.config settings manually using the ConfigurationManager.GetSection("paypal") but also with no luck.

Thanks in advance, I hope you can help me!

My Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <paypal>
    <settings>
      <add name="mode" value="sandbox"/>
      <add name="connectionTimeout" value="360000"/>
      <add name="requestRetries" value="1"/>
      <add name="clientId" value="CENSORED"/>
      <add name="clientSecret" value="CENSORED" />
    </settings>
  </paypal>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="myproject.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date 
        [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="PayPalLogger" value="PayPal.Log.Log4netLogger" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="noReplyPassword" value="hsG3Coj53U" />
    <add key="systemMailPassword" value="F3cLq4gEb5" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <trust level="Full" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="120" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Autodiscover XML to PHP" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="*autodiscover.xml" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}autodiscover.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.9.6.0" newVersion="6.9.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=myproject.com;       port=3306;database=myproject;uid=myproject;password=CENSORED;" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices,          MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you by chance have .NET 4.6 RC installed?  We're tracking this issue [over on GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/issues/101).

Comment: Looks like I have .NET 4.6, yes. I'll reinstall it and then retry with .NET 4.5.1 instead, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling .NET Framework 4.6 RC as suggested by Jason Z, fixed my issue.

I'm sure in newer releases of the PayPal SDK it'll work with .NET 4.6, but for now it doesn't, unfortunately.

It also seems to work when installing PayPal SDK 1.4.2 instead of 1.4.3.